# Are there only 2 clopen sets on real plane?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

How can I prove that the only open and closed sets on the real plane are empty set and real plane itself? Preferably by using order theory.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the topology? The standard one? And why do you want to use order theory? How about just using topology...

Comment: Point-set topology.

I do not have much topology background. Of course you can prove it by just using topology, it will help others in future, but not me right now.

Comment: How do you intend to use order theory on the plane (which I interpret as $\mathbb R^2$), given that it is not ordered?

Comment: The plane is connected, so it has no nontrivial clopen sets.

Comment: @AlexBecker, I interpreted $R^2$. Secondly, I wanted to see a prove by using a not clopen set and taking points inside and outside of this set in an order. I am not sure whether I could express myself clearly.

Comment: @Jared; Yes, but how could you prove it by using mathematical terms?

Comment: Do you mean a sequence, rather than "an order"?

Comment: Path connectedness implies connectedness implies there are only two clopen subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Can you find a line segment containing any two points of the plane?

Comment: @user69810: To prove that path-connectedness implies connectedness, one has to show that intervals are connected, which is just what the OP is having troubles with.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like: If there exists non-trivial clopen set $U$, then $U^c$ is also a nontrivial clopen set. Make a path from $x\in U$, to $y\in U^c$.

$l(t) = ty+(1-t)x$ for $t\in [0,1]$.  Since both $U,U^c$ are closed you can show that $x_0 = l(\alpha)$ lies in both $U,U^c$ where $\alpha = \sup\{t:l(t)\in U\}$

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't know $\inf\{t:l(t)\in U^c\}=\sup\{t:l(t)\in U\}$. Just take the supremum, then it works.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.;) You can take both for $\alpha$, but they might not be equal.

Comment: Hi, how do you know that $l(\alpha)$ lies in both $U$ and $U^c$? Thank you.